# Vanilla WPF application hangs on one customer's machine

Tags: wpf, freeze

At a customer, one of our WPF applications started to hang. When trying to reproduce the problem with a minimal working example, I discovered that even the most basic (non-trivial) WPF application will hang on that machine.

**Example A**: Create a new C# WPF project in Visual Studio 2008. Change nothing, compile it and run it on the customer's machine. It will run.

**Example B**: Take Example A, and add a TextBlock to the main form `Window1`:

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>Test</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Compile the application and run it on the customer's machine. It will hang: The title bar and the window border is visible, the inside is transparent and the window does not react to anything (cannot be moved or closed). The application must be shut down using the task manager.

Obviously, this customer's WPF is broken. Is this a known issue, i.e., has anyone encountered it before and already knows how to solve it (e.g. reinstall .net 3.5 SP1, etc.)?

The development machine is W7SP1, the customer's machine is XP (probably SP3, didn't check).

Comment: Fine print: I know that *technically* this is not a programming question. However, it does not fit either on Serveradmin nor on Superuser, and this is an issue most likely encountered by developers. Hence, I posted it here.

Comment: Can be a video driver issue perhaps?

Comment: Did you try other WPF applications not developed by you, i.e. downloaded from the web in executable form?

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks for the hint, I'll try that when I get a chance.

Comment: I've had problems with the font cache process hanging before - can't say I know why or how to solve it, but look in Task Manager, see if it's spinning. Might be a clue.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks, I'll have a look at that as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Tom Dudfield's instructions to clear the WPF font cache](http://tom.dudfield.com/2010/08/09/wpf-not-responding-on-launch/).  It's worked for me for several users.

Comment: Nice to know!! Bump this guy's points a few. I'm sure I'll have to search and find this again.

Answer (score 0):

Also, I recently had this experience in a more complicated example.

**FLAILING:**

I tried this cleaning the font cache thing and it did nothing for my hanging application, but YMMV.  Nevertheless it seems harmless.

Also tried NGEN'ing all the framework stuff but that did not resolve the problem.

**SOLUTION:**

In my MVVM app, I have an ItemsControl (generic, not a real ListBox) on a complex control dropped on a tab page.  The ItemsControl presented about 14 'data rows' consisting of custom controls bound to a small collection, which itself was surrounded by a ScrollViewer.  With the ScrollViewer surrounding, **selected computers** would thrash endlessly and get stuck.  Commenting out the Xaml made the app behave totally OK which pretty much ruled out problems in the backing ViewModel.

Removing the surrounding ScrollViewer eliminated the problem and it was not really necessary anyway.  I do suspect that the real problem lurks in a style somewhere but frankly did not have time or patience to investigate further...

Fragment

```
<!--<ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Grid.Row="7" -->
    <ItemsControl   Grid.Row="7" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"    
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Name="FileSettingsList"  
            ItemsSource="{Binding MigratorFiles.FilesCollection}"   
            BorderThickness="2"                          
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
            Template="{StaticResource   FileNameSettingsItemsControlTemplate}"                          
            ItemsPanel="{StaticResource FileNameSettingsItemsPanelTemplate}" 
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FileNameSettingsItemDataTemplate}"  >
    </ItemsControl>
    <!-- /ScrollViewer -->
```